# dismiss a dialogfragment while it is still being created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

At what point in the creation life cycle of a `DialogFragment` can I safely dismiss it, so that it is never visible to the user? My intent is that when the user rotates the screen, the `DialogFragment` goes through the creation lifecycle again, and I'd prefer for it to be recreated selectively. If `condition x`, recreate the `DialogFragment`, if `condition y`, just dismiss it while it is still being recreated so that the user never sees it in the new orientation. So, where in its creation lifecycle can I safely say, `dismiss`?

Comment: you could check if it is showing before calling dismiss ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, where would I put that? `onViewCreated`?

Comment: Or you could check the fragment/activity status before showing the dialog

Comment: would returning `null` in `onCreateDialog` selectively work?

Comment: you should refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for detail documentation of Dialog Fragment. and for more info refer [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201022/how-to-correctly-dismiss-a-dialogfragment ) . hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to control the life of `DialogFragment` in `onConfigureChanged(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

     Fragment yourDialog = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog_tag");
     if(yourDialog != null) {
        DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) yourDialog;
        df.dismiss();
     }

     if(condition x)
     {
       //here recreate your dialog
     }
}
```

Hope this idea help!