# Error inflating class fragment (when opening dialog for second time)

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I've run into this error when opening my DialogFragment. It is fine the first time I open it but If I dimiss it and then try to open it again I run into errors. This wasn't occurring untill after adding the GoogleMap fragment as well as change the fragment import to `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` from `import android.app.DialogFragment`;

I've been being told to include more code lately here (in the android S.O.) so I added a bit from the start. Let me know if I over did it.

## StackTrace:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.andrew.neighborlabour, PID: 9528
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #166: Binary XML file line #166: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.CreateJobDialog.onCreateView(CreateJobDialog.java:77)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #166: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.CreateJobDialog.onCreateView(CreateJobDialog.java:77) 
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #166: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00b7, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3420)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.CreateJobDialog.onCreateView(CreateJobDialog.java:77) 
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008) 
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

## How I am calling the Dialog:

```
new CreateJobDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

## CreateJobDialog:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.Services.Utils.Conversions;
import com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.Services.Utils.SuccessCB;
import com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.Services.listings.Listing;
import com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.Services.listings.ListingManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CreateJobDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "CreateJob";
    private final String TAG = "Create Job Dialog";

    final int MAX_DURATION = 4 * 8; //in 15 minute intervals
    final int MAX_COMPENSATION = 100;

    View view;

    DatePickerDialog datePicker;
    TimePickerDialog timePicker;

    TextView etTitle;
    TextView etDescription;
    TextView etAddress;
    TextView tvCompensation;
    TextView tvDuration;
    TextView tvStartDate;
    TextView tvStartTime;

    GoogleMap map;

    Button btCreate;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = 12;
    int minute = 0;

    int duration = 15;
    int compensation = 10;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_create_job, null);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        setUpGui(view);
        initTextValues();
        setButtonListeners();

        return view;
    }

    void setUpGui(View view){
        etTitle = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        etDescription = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
        etAddress = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        tvCompensation = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.tvCompensation);
        tvDuration = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
        tvStartDate = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.tvStartDate);
        tvStartTime = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.tvStartTime);
        btCreate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btCreate);
    }

    void initTextValues(){
        tvStartDate.setText( (month+1) + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        tvStartTime.setText( "12:00");
        tvCompensation.setText("$10");
        tvDuration.setText("0:15");
    }

    void setButtonListeners(){
        tvStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //showStartDatePicker();
            }
        });
        tvDuration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //showDurationPicker();
            }
        });
        tvStartTime.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //showTimePicker();
            }
        });
        tvCompensation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //showCompensationPicker();
            }
        });
        btCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //createJob();
            }
        });
        etAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                //updateMap();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        Log.e("map", "ready");
    }
}
```

## CreateJobXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.andrew.neighborlabour.CreateJobDialog">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:text="Create Job"
            android:textAppearance="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Job Title"
                android:id="@+id/etTitle"/>

            <EditText
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:id="@+id/etAddress"/>

            <EditText
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:lines="3"
                android:id="@+id/etDescription"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width = "300dp"
                    android:text="Compensation: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCompensation"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width = "300dp"
                    android:text="Duration: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/tvDuration"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width = "300dp"
                    android:text="Date: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStartDate"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width = "300dp"
                    android:text="Time: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStartTime"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                tools:context=".MapsActivity"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Job"
        android:id="@+id/btCreate"
        android:onClick="Create"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## And for good measure the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andrew.neighborlabour">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <application
        android:name=".ParseProject"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB151f1l-Rr5H3jWNYTTWlIFklHbDpGchg"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".UI.auth.LoginActivity"
            android:label="login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UI.jobListings.ListingDetailActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UI.auth.RegisterActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UI.auth.ProfileActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you problem is identified at this line in the trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #166: Duplicate id 0x7f0e00b7, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Check that you are not reusing ids for fragments and are properly dismissing your `DialogFragment`. See this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201022/how-to-correctly-dismiss-a-dialogfragment) and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for info on dismissing `DialogFragment's.

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly you have another `SupportMapFragment` inflated in the view hierarhy (i.e. in the activity's xml itself). Now you are trying to inflate a new one with the same id `R.id.map` in the `DialogFragment`. That cannot happen, because it would turn out there are two views with the same id in the same activity's view hierarchy.

From the error stacktrace:

> Duplicate id 0x7f0e00b7, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Change the id of `SupportMapFragment` in the `CreateJobXML`:

```
<LinearLayout>
...
    <fragment   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/map1" // another id
                tools:context=".MapsActivity"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changing the name doesn't end the errors which  makes me believe maybe I'm not destroying my mapFragment on dismissal of the dialog